# Aggregations work in standalone but not in sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm currently trying the aggregations with MongoDB using the json found here : http://media.mongodb.org/zips.json

So, I imported it thousands of time and then I tried this command :

```
db.CO_villes.aggregate({$group:{_id:"$state",population:{$sum:"$pop"}}})
```

And I got this error :

```
2019-04-24T13:49:19.579+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "unrecognized field 'mergeByPBRT'",
    "code" : 9,
    "codeName" : "FailedToParse",
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1556113758, 2),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1556113758, 2),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
} : aggregate failed :
```

I have a sharded cluster with 3 MongoDB instances. 
I can face this issue too when I try to get the indexes with "Compass".

I tried to export the data and to remove the id field using the "sed" command (because my Ids were not all with "ObjectID")and to import it but I still face this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by creating a 3.6 cluster instead of a 4.0.6. So I think this is a bug related to the new versions of MongoDB.

Comment: The same problem!!! it works on v4.0.5 cluster, i think this bug started from v4.0.6.

Comment: Glad to hear that you encountered the same problem and then know that it is a bug related to version 4.0.6. Thank you

Comment: I believe this issue is only possible if your shard `mongod` servers are using 4.0.6 or older and you've upgraded your `mongos` to 4.0.7+. If all of your cluster components are definitely running the same version of `mongod` and `mongos`, it would be best to post a new question on [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/mongodb) with more details of your environment including the specific `mongod` and `mongos` versions used.